# Open cv error in pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda

I am getting the following error in pycharm (windows version). I have installed opencv using Anaconda. In addition, Pycharm auto-completion is detecting cv2. Can somebody tell what could be the possible issue? Thanks in advance

```
File "C:/Users/DELL/Pranavan/PyCharm Projects/QE/SIFT_implementation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are using Anaconda, but the Interpreter Pycharm is using seems to be searching for packages in `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages` which does not look like an Anaconda installation directory.

Make sure that Pycharm is using the correct interpreter (your Anaconda Python Version) by going to `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`

Answer (score 0):

When using Anaconda, the Interpreter Pycharm seems to be searching for packages in Anaconda(Python)

```
Note on setting the interpreter:
File - Default Settings - Project Interpreter - Wheel - Add local -
System Interpreter - … - /home/milab/anaconda3/bin/python - OK to all
```

and then

```
​​File - Settings - Project : ### - Project Interpreter - Python 3.6 ~/anaconda3/bin/python - Ok
```

I hope you to solve problem.